# how can I understand a register correctly?

Tags: vhdl, vivado

There is a problem always bothers me. I have written 3 similar functions in VHDL, code and simulation see below. out_1 and input_sig_2 are identicial with input. But out_1 is delayed for 1 clock cycle when compared with input_sig_1. Can someone tell me why is this happens? Is that because input_sig_1 is signal and input is port?

Any response will be highly appreciated!

```
input_sig_1 <= input;
out_2 <= input_sig_2;
process(clock)
begin   
    if rising_edge(clock) then
        if reset = '1' then
            out_0 <= '0';
            out_1 <= '0';
            input_sig_2 <= '0';

        else
            out_0 <= input;
            out_1 <= input_sig_1;
            input_sig_2 <= input;
        end if;
    end if;
end process;
```

[image]

Comment: Signal updates are scheduled for the same or a future simulation time via a projected output waveform queue and occur in an earlier part of a simulation cycle than resuming processes execute then suspend. A waveform element without an after clause is assumed to have **after** 0 ns as one. A signal assigned the value  of a signal event concurrent with the clock event will not be updated until the next simulation cycle missing the current clock edge but not the next when simulation time has advanced. Provide a [mcve].

Comment: Instead of using signal assignments to affect name changes you could use aliases.

Answer (score -1):

You are changing the signal input at the same time, when a rising clock edge occurs. So the question is, which of both signal changes reaches first the clocked process. This depends at how many delta cycles you are inserting during the signal path from the testbench to the process. You insert by "input_sig_1 <= input;" one additional delta cycle, so the signal input_1_sig changes after the rising clock edge has reached the process. To avoid such problems you always should change input signals at the inactive clock edge, in your case at the falling clock edge (or at any other time, when no rising clock edge is assigned).

Comment: thanks for your response. That means data paths out_0 and out_2 are reasonable, and data path out_1 should always be avoided?

Comment: You should not avoid data path out_1. You must be aware that if you insert simulator delta cycles in your data- or clock-path (by "<=" operators), then the signals will be delayed differently (in number of delta cycles, not in time), so that without counting all your assignments in the data path, you do not know which signal arrives first at the clocked process. But as counting is difficult and error prone, you should change your stimulation: Never change a data input to your design at the same time, when a rising clock edge happens. This will solve all these delta-cycle-problems for all time.

Comment: You cannot give this answer without the op posting the testbench. While it likely this is a Delta problem, the answer is to synchronise all signals to a clock, rather than use absolute delays for dut inputs.

Comment: thanks @Tricky and Matthias. I think I found the problem, I was giving a blocking assignment in my TB, as I changed it to non-blocking assignment, this problem never shows again. Last question, does delta-cycle-problem plays an important roll in FPGA design? Or it's just a dont care problem managed by Vivado or Quartus?

Comment: Delta cycles at data signals are not a problem. You will get an additional delta cycle at each "<=" assignment and at each process call. But on clock signals delta cycles are dangereous. They are not handled by Vivado or Quartus, but can lead to a different behavior of your design in simulation and reality (FPGA). So connect your clock signal always directly to the clocked processes and never insert stuff like clock gating.  If you must introduce deltacycles to clock signals, you must be very careful and try to eliminate the effect of the deltacycles, for example by delaying all clock signals.

Comment: Delta cycles are a simulation only problem. VHDL needs something to use to simulation digital logic, and the delta cycle model is the one VHDL uses. So signal assignments are scheduled to be updated in the current delta (or on some future delta if an `after` keyword is used). So an assignment can set off a chain of signal assignments on multiple subsequent deltas within the same "wall clock" time. In your case I assume you updated the data at the same time as the clock, so the dut saw the data update 1 delta before the clock changed. deltas have no meaning for actual synthesis, however.